# how can i C# Deserialize JSON list WinForm Combobox?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I would like to print out the contents of the array selected in Combo Box 2 after selecting an item in Combo Box 1.

[image]

Like this picture

```
{
"Movie": [
    "Action",
    {
        "Mad Max": "1979",
        "Terminator": "1984"
    },
    "SF",
    {
        "Star Wars": "1979"
    }
]
```

}

The JSON file looks like this

The class is defined like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<object> Movie { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't know how to read what's in the object.

I appreciate any help provided. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The attached JSON and the model class for deserialization don't have any relation. =|

Comment: sorry, it's my mistakes, I revised the text

Comment: Really important to understand that arrays use brackets [] and objects use braces {}. In the above question you would use [] for Action and SF, then put {}'s around each movie, so you can have an object and not just key value pairs. You can do it any way you'd like, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the `Movie` property contains a pattern with the action type first followed by a dictionary/object,

1. Deserialize JSON as `Root`.
2. Get the index from `root.Movie` by matching the value with the selected action type.
3. Deserialize the next item by the index (`index + 1`) in `root.Movie` as `Dictionary<string, string>` type.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

Root root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
int index = root.Movie.FindIndex(x => x.ToString() == selected);
        
Dictionary<string, string> dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(root.Movie[index + 1].ToString());

// Print output
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bD6qUp)